# error creating repository - Not a managed type when springboot with h2

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, entity, h2

I get the above error even after introducing the entity scan. I will add my code below.

main class

```
package com.idealo.demoapp1;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaAuditing;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;


@SpringBootApplication
//@EnableJpaAuditing
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.idealo.demoapp1.repository")
@EntityScan("com.idealo.demoapp1.entity")
@ComponentScan("com.*")
public class DemoApp1Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DemoApp1Application.class, args);
 }
}
```

controller

```
package com.idealo.demoapp1.controller;

import com.idealo.demoapp1.entity.Item;
//import org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.schemagen.xmlschema.List;
import com.idealo.demoapp1.service.ItemService;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import java.util.List;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(path = "/item")
public class ItemController {

//    @Autowired
    ItemService itemService;
    
    @GetMapping
    @ResponseBody
    public List<Item> getAllItems() {
         return itemService.getAllItems();
    }
}
```

service

```
package com.idealo.demoapp1.service;

import com.idealo.demoapp1.entity.Item;
import com.idealo.demoapp1.repository.ItemRepository;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.List;

@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Service
@Transactional
public class ItemService {

//    @Autowired
    ItemRepository itemRepository;

    public List<Item> getAllItems() {
        return itemRepository.findAll();
    }

}
```

repository

```
package com.idealo.demoapp1.repository;

import com.idealo.demoapp1.entity.Item;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.UUID;

@Repository
public interface ItemRepository extends JpaRepository<Item, UUID> {

}
```

entity

```
package com.idealo.demoapp1.entity;

import com.sun.istack.NotNull;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.CreatedDate;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.LastModifiedDate;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.support.AuditingEntityListener;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.UUID;

@Entity
@Table(name = "item")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Builder
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class Item {
    
    @Id
    private UUID id;

    @Column
    private String product_name;

    @Column
    private String producer;

    @Column
    private String product_desc;

    @Column
    private String product_picture;

    @Column
    private String current_price;

    @Column
    private String best_price;

    @Column
    private String best_price_date;

    @Column
    private String product_rating;
    
}
```

h2 configs in application.properties

```
server.servlet.context-path=/${spring.application.name}
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:idealo;TRACE_LEVEL_FILE=4
spring.datasource.username=idealo
spring.datasource.password=123
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.open-in-view=true
spring.application.name=idealo-backend
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
```

error

```
Error creating bean with name 'itemRepository' defined in com.idealo.demoapp1.repository.ItemRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on DemoApp1Application: Not a managed type: class com.idealo.demoapp1.entity.Item
```

Folder structure

[image]

pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.idealo</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo-app1</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>demo-app1</name>
    <description>Demo project with Spring Boot for idealo</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
<!--        <maven.compiler.release>8</maven.compiler.release>-->
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.persistence/javax.persistence-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.24</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.cedarsoftware</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-util</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0</version>
        </dependency>

<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->




        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

I have gone through similar questions and have tried the solutions without success.
I greatly appreciate if someone can assist me in finding the root cause for this issue

Comment: What is the version of spring-boot/spring-data-jpa you are using? Try removing all annotations from `DemoApp1Application` except `@SpringBootApplication`

Comment: I use spring boot 3.0.0 and java 1.8 versions. will add my pom also to the question. I removed all the annotations except @springbootapplication but still get the same error

Comment: Issue is with your spring-boot version. I added answer with solution, please try that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

spring-boot 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT is a snapshot version and not GA(released) version. If you use any latest release version like below, it should work

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.1</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```